# Unit testing asp.net core. build all projects in solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

So I have 4 projects in my solution and all of them needs to be built in order for the test to work.

I have one common class that holds a lot of values that needs to be mocked or accessed in the test.
How ever, these values are all null in the test method and if I try to give them a value I get   System.TypeInitializationException.

I believe that the class is not built when I run the test but there might be some other issue.

Any idea of how to do this?

btw im using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

//Mak

Comment: If your test project depends on the other project (has the other project linked as a dependency in the .csproj file), then the dependent projects will be built prior to the tests being run. If it wasn't, the test project's build would fail. 

Could you give a minimal reproducible example of a failing test and how you're setting it up?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.